# Is it possible to force ALSA / pavucontrol to not let auto microphone gain be changed by video conference systems (Zoom, Google Meets,...)

Tags: sound, usb, alsa, microphone, pavucontrol

i am on an Ubuntu 20.04 and my USB microphone works like a charm. Since one of the last updates Google Meets is automatically setting the Gain of the microphone to 100%, which leads to a very "crust metal band" sound (that is what my colleagues told me ;)). In many video conference systems is an option to switch off the automatic adjustion of the microphone gain. Unhappily in Google Meets there is no such setting (if i was blind, i would be happy to find it!).

So my question is: can i somehow force ALSA / pavucontrol to not let Google Meets set the automatic gain of the microphone? I would love to get rid of checking it over and over again!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Crust Metal Band distortion pedal(s) for Guitar and Base Guitar works two major ways, Overdrive and Distortion, perhaps this case Fuzz is the word. It is one of the variation of distortion which is given by a chain of cheap electric amplifiers.

The most simple way to get it without pedals or amplifiers; is to scream very close to the microphone. It will do.

So let's not do this by yourself or prevent the machine from over amplifying your voice is to set the proper microphone level at the first place.

System settings (or whatever) > Sound > Input Tab

[image: Input_level]

Use Input Volume Slider to adjust the recording level not to exceed the blue gauge. And remember yourself the distance between the microphone and your voice volume when you are doing this.
If the distance increased by 2 times, the sound got weaker 1/4. And it is true to the half distance makes 4 times power. This is given by Ohm's law.

However, you can install some of Google Chrome extensions to not allow browser to change microphone level automatically.
**Disable Automatic Gain Control** or **Google Meet Volume Control** are the proper ones, I believe.